# Merge lowest price into get_queryset view

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am trying to generate a `get_queryset` result in my Django view with the `ProductDetails` model merged with the lowest price from the Price model for each Product.

## Models

```
class ProductDetail(models.Model):
    productId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
    brandId = models.ForeignKey('brands.Brand')

class Price(models.Model):
    storeId = models.ForeignKey('Store')
    productId = models.ForeignKey('ProductDetail')
    price = models.DecimalField('Price', max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    storePriceUrl = models.CharField('Product url', max_length=300)
    inStock = models.BooleanField('In stock', default=True)

class Store(models.Model):
    storeId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
    storeText = models.CharField('Store', max_length=100)   
    storeSlug = models.SlugField(max_length=100)
    storeURL = models.CharField('URL', max_length=100, default='http://')
    storeImage = models.FileField(upload_to='stores/storelogos/')
```

## View (ATTEMPT :-)

```
class Products(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'products.html'
    context_object_name = 'product_list'
    def get_queryset(self): 
        pdlist = ProductDetail.objects.select_related().all()
        pricelist = Price.objects.filter().values_list('productId_id').annotate(Min('price')).order_by('price')[0]
        result_list = itertools.chain(pdlist, pricelist)
        return result_list
```

I'm trying to get all the product related data back with the lowest price (and related details) from the Price model for each Product.  Note that I'm only a couple of weeks into Django so still learning the ropes.
Thank-you for any help in advance.

Comment: The view code also includes: import itertools

Comment: What are you getting in return, is there any error?

Comment: Also to my prev comment, can you tell what kid of data you need to display?, merging two different models seems like a bad idea..

Comment: I'm getting an Exception Type: NoReverseMatch on the brand.  Should I simply be able to access the price with a more simple get_queryset of "return Seat.objects.select_related().all()"?  How would I then display the lowest price?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `productId` field into:

```
productId = models.ForeignKey('ProductDetail', related_name='prices')
```

Then use the following query:

```
pdlist = ProductDetail.objects.annotate(min_price=Min('prices__price'))\
                              .order_by('min_price')
```

Comment: Thanks mariodev, that worked a treat.  How would I then access the other fields in the price model corresponding to the lowest price in the template?  i.e the storePriceUrl

Comment: It's not so simple with django ORM, however [this blog post](http://blog.roseman.org.uk/2010/08/14/getting-related-item-aggregate/) explains how to get around it.